# Void function error (value computed is not used)

Tags: c

Hi all I have tried a couple variations of my code and I can't figure out how to resolve these warnings.

- The objective is to create a modular representation of the monty hall problem in c

**Problem**

- My **outputFinalResult** function fails to give me correct output

**Error Messages**

```
 -  gcc -Wall monteball.c

monteball.c: In function ‘determineOutcomeStay’:

monteball.c:125:7: warning: value computed is not used [-Wunused-value]

monteball.c:127:3: warning: value computed is not used [-Wunused-value]

monteball.c: In function ‘determineOutcomeSwitch’:

monteball.c:134:7: warning: value computed is not used [-Wunused-value]

monteball.c:136:3: warning: value computed is not used [-Wunused-value]

monteball.c: In function ‘getFinalChoice’:

monteball.c:119:1: warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
```

an aside should I be worried about this warning?

**Code**

```
void outputFinalResult (int winStay, int winSwitch, int stayCount, int switchCount);
//function is 4 print statements using arguments calculated by determineOutcome functions
int main (int argc, char * argv [])
{
  srand(time(NULL));
  int counter = 10000;
  int i = 0;
  int winStay;
  int winSwitch = 0;
  int stayCount;
  int switchCount = 0;
  int firstChoice;
  int grandPrize;
  int revealedDoor;
  int finalChoice;

  for (i = 0; i < counter; i++)
  {
    firstChoice = getUserChoice ();

    grandPrize = determinePrizeLocation ();

    revealedDoor = revealDoor (firstChoice, grandPrize);

    finalChoice = getFinalChoice (firstChoice, grandPrize, revealedDoor);

    if(finalChoice == firstChoice)
    {
      determineOutcomeStay(finalChoice, grandPrize, &winStay, &stayCount);
    } else
    {
      determineOutcomeSwitch(finalChoice, grandPrize, &winSwitch, &switchCount);
    }

  }

  outputFinalResult (winStay, winSwitch, stayCount, switchCount);
  return 0;
}
int getFinalChoice (int firstChoice, int grandPrize, int revealedDoor)
{
  int finalChoice;
  int switchProbability = rand () % 2 + 1; // 50% chance of keeping or switching choice                                                                                            

  if (switchProbability == 1) // Represents user keeping their choice                                                                                                              
  {
    return firstChoice;
  }

  else if (switchProbability == 2) // Represents user switching their choice                                                                                                       
  {
    finalChoice = rand () % 3 + 1; // Randomizes finalChoice btw 1-3                                                                                                             

    while (finalChoice == revealedDoor || finalChoice == firstChoice) // Ensures that finalChoice isn't the door that was eliminated or                                          
    {                                                                 // the door that was initially selected                                                                  
      finalChoice = rand () % 3 + 1;
    }

    return finalChoice;
  }
}

void determineOutcomeStay(int choice, int grandPrize, int * winStay, int * stayCount)
{
  if(choice == grandPrize)
  {
    *winStay++;
  }
 *stayCount++;
}

void determineOutcomeSwitch(int choice, int grandPrize, int * winSwitch, int * switchCount)
{
  if(choice == grandPrize)
  {
    *winSwitch++;
  }
  *switchCount++;
}
```

Sorry for the long post just trying to give all the info need to receive a good answer. Please message me if additional info is needed. Thanks.

Comment: The compiler is complaining about functions `determineOutcomeStay`, `determineOutcomeSwitch` and `getFinalChoice`. What do they look like?

Comment: Your error isn't in `main`. The warnings mention monteball.c lines 125 to 136 (that's what the numbers after it mean)

Comment: You should be concerned about "control reaches end of non-void function", but as the others said, you actually have to show the code that is giving these warnings for us to be more specific.

Comment: If you are not using returned value then no need to collect it. you can change `getFinalChoice` to return `void` or return some value at the end of function.

Comment: @user3386754 can you post this code on your question window and delete from here?

Comment: You get a warning message that memtions function X. You post a question that does not include the code of function X. Fair enough, people here are expected to hack your computer and obtain the code, but you could at least post your IP address to make their lives a bit easier.

Comment: Sorry my mistake. Even with all these sarcastic remarks I do appreciate that you are all willing to help me. I edited my original post to include the necessary functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most warnings you want to fix, they're pretty good at finding bad behaviour. In your particular case:

The line

```
*stayCount++;
```

doesn't do what you think. [Operator precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence) says that in this case the ++ comes first. Ergo it actually means this:

```
*(stayCount++);
```

Thus the warning, `stayCount` is changed but not used. Put parenthesis around any expression that might be ambiguous, this is one of those times

```
(*stayCount)++;
```

In `getFinalChoice` the error is self explanitory, "control reaches end of non-void function". In other words, there's a path through the function that doesn't result in a `return` getting called. I'll let you find it ;)

Comment: Thank you very much I've been tearing my hair out for the past week rewriting this code a multiple times. As for the    getFinalChoice function I'm failing to see the undetected path do you have any hints?

Comment: @user3386754 1: Start from the very last brace and work backward through the function to figure out how you can arrive there. 2: Draw a tree of all the possible paths taken making sure that you have a fork for every if statement.

Comment: Hey all thought I should officially confirm that all previous errors and warnings are resolved my return of finalChoice in getFinalChoice was in the wrong position causing the "control reaches end of non-void function warning". It should be outside the second if statement. Once again thank you all for your help.